# Using Vim keybinding to scroll page up and down in tmux on Mac

Tags: linux, mac, keyboard-shortcuts, vim, tmux

I'm using Tmux on MacOS10.14.6 and want to scroll up and down with vim's keybindings. I can scroll with the arrow key using <kbd>Ctrl-b</kbd>, then <kbd>[</kbd> and then the arrow keys (<kbd>↑</kbd>, <kbd>↓</kbd>, <kbd>←</kbd>, <kbd>→</kbd>). Instead of the arrow keys I tried vim's keybinding (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>) as explained [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1084487/scrolling-on-mac-with-tmux-and-iterm) without success. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This Q & A is not Mac-specific, as it resolved the same problem I was having on RHEL 8.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the tmux man page, it seems that if your EDITOR or VISUAL environment variable has the string "vi" in it anywhere, it may set your tmux to use vi key bindings.

You probably need to be in "copy mode" for the scrolling to work. That's what the Ctrl-b then [ does for emacs bindings. Try entering copy mode (maybe "[" for vi keys) and then use Ctrl-e (scroll down) and Ctrl-y (scroll up). Again, I got these from the man page. It helps to search for "bindings" there.

Finally, the "bind-key" command can help you to change the key bindings if you want to change what scrolls up and down. The "list-keys" command may help you see your current bindings.